# plt.scatter() adds white border around image

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot

When I use plt.scatter to plot a point on an image I also get a white border (all 4 sides) on the image. How can I remove the border and just keep the original image size?

**No border**

```
# plotting
plt.imshow(image)
```

**Border**

```
# plotting
plt.imshow(image)

# put a blue dot at (10, 20)
plt.scatter([location[1]], [location[0]])
```

Comment: I can't replicate... If the point is within the image, i don't get a border. if the point on one side of image, border (or axis limit) is extended so that the point can be seen...

Comment: The result of the code in the quesiton would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DERBU.png). The problem is thus not reproducible. Please edit your question with a [mcve] and a clear problem description (best also an image of the undesired output).